# How to check if the user has shared the link on facebook

Tags: c#, .net, frameworks

Well, I'm creating a system event in which checks whether a user shared a link.
I did an extensive search, but found nothing about how to verify that the user shared this link.
My website is in **C#**, I did not find how to check for Code Behind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use sharer.php because it a code and users can change the code in F12 - Inspect Element, so https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com.br try it and enjoy and good luck

Comment: Well, it returns some value? Or do I have to do the scan after the click?